# error following first steps of scrapy tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

[I am following this tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). After writing the first spider it directs me to use the command `scrapy crawl quotes`, but I seem to obtain an error.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Here is the error that I encounter:

```
 PS C:\Users\BB\desktop\scrapy\tutorial\spiders> scrapy crawl quotes

 2018-09-12 13:55:06 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started
 (bot: tutorial)

 2018-09-12 13:55:06 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0,
 libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted
 17.5.0, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2o 27 Mar
 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0

 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py",
 line 69, in load

 return self._spiders[spider_name]

 KeyError: 'quotes'


 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in
 <module>

 sys.exit(scrapy.cmdline.execute())

 File "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line
 150, in execute

 _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)

 File "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line
 90, in _run_print_help

 func(*a, **kw)

 File "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line
 157, in _run_command

 cmd.run(args, opts)

 File
 "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py",
 line 57, in run

 self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)

 File "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line
 170, in crawl

 crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)

 File "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line
 198, in create_crawler

 return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)

 File "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line
 202, in _create_crawler

 spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)

 File "C:\Users\BB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py",
 line 71, in load

 raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))

 KeyError: 'Spider not found: quotes'
```

Comment: The link seems to be dead for me. You'll have to show the relevant code if you want any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html, sorry about that this is the right link it just had something attached to it

Comment: You have to put the code here, not just a link.

Comment: @Xan-Kun Clark-Davis sorry, new here. thanks. I edited the post and included the code.

Comment: You need to use `crawl` command from a folder with `scrapy.cfg` file. I'm not sure but may be you need to `cd ..\..` first?

Comment: @ganabass your comment helped me to figure it out. much thanks.

Comment: @brass Thanks for putting the code in. The problem with links is, when they go down (and sooner or later they all will :-) ), the question doesn't make sense anymore to others. I also edit the question and put the error in code format. It is usually easier to read for programmers due to the monospaced font used ;-) I hope that's ok, if you don't like it, just revert the change. And Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had created a folder called spiders, but the tutorial already did this for me and had a _pycache? _init__? files that were required for the command 'scrapy crawl quotes' to work. In short, I was runnning it from the wrong folder.